# Fundamental Confusion Regarding the Fundamental Group

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Consider the following question.

Let $X$ be a topological space and $x_0$ be any point in $X$.
Let $\gamma\in \pi_1(X,x_0)$ be a non-constant loop about the base point $x_0$.

> Then can it happen that $\gamma*\gamma=e_{x_0}$ (here $e_{x_0}$ denotes the constant loop)?

I don't see how this is possible.

For if $\gamma(t_0)\neq x_0$ for some $t_0>0$, then $\gamma*\gamma(t_0/2)=\gamma(t_0)\neq x_0$.

Hence $\gamma* \gamma$ is not the constant loop.

Why this confuses me is because I know for a fact that the funcdamental goup of $\mathbf RP^2$ (the real projective plane) is $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$.

So there must be a non-constant loop in $\pi_1(\mathbf RP^2,x_0)$ such that $\gamma* \gamma=e_{x_0}$, in contradiction to my previous "inference".

I must be making a stupid mistake somewhere.

Can somebody please point it out.

Thanks.

Comment: $\gamma * \gamma$ doesn't have to be equal to $e_{x_0}$, it just has to be homotopy equivalent to it.

Comment: Thank you. That clears my confusion. Although I am having a hard time visualizing such a scenario.

Comment: Visualising anything to do with $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is hard! For two nonzero loops that concatenate to a loop homotopic to the zero loop, consider the circle $S^1$ and $\gamma_1$ being a loop once clockwise round the circle, $\gamma_2$ a loop once anticlockwise round the circle. Then $\gamma_1*\gamma_2$ is homotopic to the zero loop.

Comment: I was wondering how to visualize a loop $\gamma$ such that $\gamma$ cannot be contracted to a constant loop but $\gamma*\gamma$ can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenation of two nonconstant loops can be homotopic to a constant loop (i.e. nulhomotopic), but if one of the loops is nonconstant then the concatenation itself won't be constant.